# Изменение размера сайта

Tags: css, оформление

1)Как сделать чтобы сайт располагался по центру даже при изменение масштаба(ctrl+колесиком мыши), у меня уходит в левую сторону.

2)Как сделать footer и header до конца экрана. а то при изменение масштаба только до середины

```
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
}

html {height: 100%}

body {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EFFFF4;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 135%;
    float: left;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;  /* InternetExplor 8 */
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a, a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all.0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.0s ease;
    -o-transition: all.0s ease;
    -ms-transition: all.0s ease;
    transition: all.0s ease;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/* Стили для шапки */

header {                    
    width: 98%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #BFE7E9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BFE7E9; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

header #logo {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;    
}

header #logo a{
    color: #939393;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;   
}

header #logo span {
    color: #e36565;
}

header #menuHead {
    width: 34%;
    float: left;
}

header #menuHead div {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

header #menuHead div:hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

header #regAuth {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

header #link_logout {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header #link_logout a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
/* Стили для всего документа*/
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    float: left;
}

#wrapper #bigArticle{
    width: 78%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 1%;    
    float: left;
}

#wrapper #bigArticle img, #wrapper .article img {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrapper #bigArticle h2, #wrapper .article h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #636363;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper  #bigArticle p, #wrapper .article p {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#wrapper #bigArticle div.more, #wrapper .article div.more {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #878787;
    color: #fff;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper #bigArticle div.more:hover, #wrapper .articlediv.more:hovers {
    background-color: #a2a2a2;
}

#wrapper .article {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 1%;
    float: left;
}

#wrapper .article div.more {
    width: 20%;
}

/* Техподдержка */
#wrapper input {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#wrapper input:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#wrapper input#done:hover {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper textarea {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    resize: none;
}

#wrapper #messageShow {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    float: left;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Регистрация */

#regy input {
    width: 76%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 6px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#regy input:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#pacl input {
    width: 80.3%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 6px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: yellowgreen;

}

#wrapper #pacl {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    float: left;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#pacl input {
    cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

 #regy {
    border: 2px solid #00B870;  
    padding-bottom: 21%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 33.3%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#authorized h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

#svalid_email_message {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45px;
    left: 500px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}

#svalid_password_message {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 500px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}

p.mesage_error {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 96px;
    left: 500px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Авторизация */

#log input { 
width: 76%; 
margin-left: 12%; 
float: left; 
border-radius: 20px; 
border: 1px solid silver; 
padding: 6px; 
color: black; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
font-size: 1.2em; 
} 

#log input:focus { 
border: 2px solid black; 
} 

#recl input { 
width: 80%; 
margin-left: 12%; 
float: left; 
border-radius: 20px; 
border: 1px solid silver; 
padding: 6px; 
color: black; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
font-size: 1.2em; 
background-color: yellowgreen; 
} 

#recl input { 
cursor: pointer; 
} 

#leg h1 { 
margin-bottom: 40px; 
margin-top: 15%; 
font-size: 32px; 
} 

#log { 
border: 2px solid #00B870; 
padding-bottom: 15%; 
margin-left: 35%; 
margin-right: 33.3%; 
margin-top: 60px; 
}

p.amesage_error {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 195px;
    left: 500px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#lvalid_email_message {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 195px;
    left: 501px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#lvalid_password_message {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 195px;
    left: 501px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 13px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 319px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Стили для личной странице */

#wrapper #personal_page {
    width: 76%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 2%;
}

#wrapper .banner {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Стили для Footer */

footer {
    width: 98%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #FF0004;
    border-top: 1px solid #BFE7E9;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer #social {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

footer #social img {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

footer #Vk img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

footer #rights {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#page-wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

footer, #page-wrap:after {height: 10px}

#page-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: было бы круто, если бы показали стили, которые у вас отвечают за footer и header, а также body или враппер сайта, от там и можна смотреть почему у вас убегает

Comment: пару минут, сейчас кину

Comment: @Oleksandr готово

Answer (score 0):

1) нужно задать ширину для контейнера всего сайта и прописать margin: 0 auto;
2)
насчет футера:
На сайтах обычно делают так, чтобы боди был разделен на два огромных блока: мейн-контент и футер.

К мейн контенту в стилях пишут: flex: 1 0 auto;

к футеру: flex: 0 0 auto;

и к их обертке (боди):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100vh;
```

и все волшебным образом встает на свои места (не забывай для IE добавить префиксы: -ms-flex: 1 0 auto; рекомендую этот сервис на первое время https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/)

а хедер достаточно просто вставить в мейн контент на самую высокую позицию, чтоб он был сверху

Comment: Увидел ваш код, ужас, я бы на вашем месте все удалил и заново переверстал.
Совет: выучите Flexbox и забудьте про флоаты в 2017